# How to configure the @CosmosDBtrigger using java?

Tags: java, triggers, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

1. I'm setting up @CosmosDBTrigger, need help with the below code and also what needs to be in the name field?

I'm using below Tech stack,

JDK 1.8.0-211
apache maven 3.5.3
AzureCLI 2.0.71
.net core 2.2.401

Java:
    public class Function {

```
    @FunctionName("CosmosTrigger")
    public void mebershipProfileTrigger(
            @CosmosDBTrigger(name = "?", databaseName = 
            "*database_name*", collectionName = "*collection_name*", 
             leaseCollectionName = "leases", 
             createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true, 
             connectionStringSetting = "DBConnection") String[] items,
             final ExecutionContext context) {
                  context.getLogger().info("item(s) changed");

      }
   }
```

What do we need to provide in the name field?

local.settings.json

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
     "DBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=*Account_Endpoint*"
  }
}
```

Expected: function starts

Result:
"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.Cosmostrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB: Cannot create Collection Information for *collection_name* in database *database_name* with lease leases in database *database_name* : Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0. Newtonsoft.Json: Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: <. Path '', line 0, position 0."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this:- https://github.com/microsoft/inventory-hub-java-on-azure/blob/master/function-apps/Notify-Inventory/src/main/java/org/inventory/hub/NotifyInventoryUpdate.java

@CosmosDBTrigger(name = "document", databaseName = "db1",collectionName = "col1", connectionStringSetting = "dbstr",leaseCollectionName = "lease1", createLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true) String document,

Now when you publish put the value for dbstr as your connection string in Application Settings of Azure portal, after setting the properties just restart

Comment: Above code base is working on other machines(mac), only in my machine(windows) it is throwing the error I mentioned. Something is missing in the machine.

Comment: I'm running in my local.

Comment: I tried it to run on local system first I was required to update function app extension, which you can follow the link https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/wiki/Updating-your-function-app-extensions...... i also have storage emulator setup in my local system and have that in Values object of local.settings.json: "AzureWebJobsStorage": " UseDevelopmentStorage=true",...........................................................and i just gave the dname and collection name itself without any other symbols

Answer (score 0):

See the official samples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-cosmosdb-v2#trigger---java-example

`name` is just some identifier for your Function. The error you are getting is because you are telling the Trigger that the Collection you want to monitor your changes in is called "collection_name" and it's inside a database called "database_name". 
Please use the real correct values for them, they should be pointing to an existing Collection, and your connection string `DBConnection` needs to be in the correct format of: `AccountEndpoint=https://<your-account-name>.documents.azure.com:443/;AccountKey=<your-account-key>;`(you can get it from the Azure Portal).

Comment: Above code base is working on other machines(mac), only in my machine(windows) it is throwing the error I mentioned. Something is missing in the machine.

Comment: The error is thrown when the Trigger cannot find the collections. Could you share the real Trigger code? Are the values  of the attributes really `"*database_name*"` and `"*collection_name*"`? Did you verify that they exist in the account?

Comment: Yes, this account is existing and moreover same code base is working in my mac but not in windows.

Comment: Can you update the code then? Because ` "DBConnection": "AccountEndpoint=*Account_Endpoint*"` is not a valid Cosmos DB Connection string format, are you specifying the AccountKey in the code that works? The error you see comes from here https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions/blob/dev/src/WebJobs.Extensions.CosmosDB/Trigger/CosmosDBTriggerAttributeBindingProvider.cs#L160, and the error text seems to indicate some problem parsing the configuration. Are you using maybe an environment variable that is not set on your Windows machine?